# How is the RMS value greater than its mean square value?

Tags: power-spectral-density

Currently learning about PSD curves to which I have a query regarding the attached curve.

Why is the RMS value greater than its mean square value. I understand the RMS to be the the square root of the area under the curve and thus should always be less than the area of the curve[image].

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: err.. $\sqrt{\frac14} = \frac12 > \frac14$, meaning that $\sqrt{x}$ can be larger than $x$! (That's the case for any $0<x<1$.)

Comment: OK Thanks. This raises questions from a random vibrations perspective.